# C# ASP .Net - Dot Matrix Printer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, printing

I researched but I didn't found a clear way to print a text into a dot matrix printer from a system web.

The idea is to use the controller layer to generate a HTML page with some words in different positions (bold and position from a table that I have) and open it on a new tab. Then the user choose the local printer do send it.

I'm looking for something very direct, like:

object.PrintText("Header Text", myFont, Bold, 0, 5); // Text, font, style, position x, position y

Till now, I didn't found anything like this.

Any ideas on how to do something like this?

Comment: If you're presenting a web page, you have no control over the printing (your code runs on the server). The only thing the consumer of the page can do is print the page through the browser.

Comment: In JavaScript, `window.print();`  Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.print